# How to display dialog header

Tags: blackberry

How do I display a dialog header/body when displaying a question Dialog ?

I think I need to extend Dialog class but im not sure what method(s) I need to override.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the [Field#add](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/Dialog.html#add%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Field%29) to add a Field to the dialog, and have it displayed as a header. You'll probably have to do a bit of tweaking in [sublayout](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/PopupScreen.html#sublayout%28int,%20int%29) and [paint](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/PopupScreen.html#paint%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics%29) to get the desired look.